# Yes/No WPF Confirmation Message Box for other culture

Tags: .net, wpf, internationalization

How to adjust text Yes/No of WPF Confirmation Message Box buttons for other culture?

Is it possible?

In fact I need to show: Si/No

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify the culture of the application thread, and you will se the buttons translated.

For example:

```
var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES"); //Spanish region
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

MessageBox.Show("Example!",
"Example!",
MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
MessageBoxImage.Question);
```

The code above will produce the next `MessageBox`

[image]

I used [this answer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/283795/77052) from [Marc](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/50182/marc) in [SOes](https://es.stackoverflow.com) as source

Answer (score 3):

You cannot localize message box buttons. They follow the OS's language. There may be some Win32 API hacks but I have no experience about those.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a style to your buttons and use a converter to do the translation from english to spanish. In the example below the titleTranslator converter is used to translate this button's text.

```
<Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border CornerRadius="6 6 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource titleTranslator}}" FontSize="44" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="{Binding Foreground, Converter={StaticResource brushConverter}}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I asked about MessageBox window http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.80).aspx